# How do I insert content after text in an html element using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem inserting text on an anchor element that has an href attribute:

```
<a href="myfile.pdf"> Contact Us</a>
```

I am trying to write the css to make the icons appear after Contact Us and any text within any anchor tag:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:after { 
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
content: url('/_assets/img/document-type-icons-2.png') no-repeat -84% 0;
}
```

It is not working like this. How can I write my css to make this happen?

Ok I got it working but how do I style the background properties such as no repeat and -84% 0.

It keeps repeating

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? This looks correct to me.

Comment: @BillyMathews agree. Works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/rY4R6/

Comment: Also, it might be worthwhile to see the compatibility factor when using attribute selectors: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ in the event you're shooting for IE 6 compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set image as `background-image` for your `:after` pseudoelement or remove anything except `url(path)` from `content` property. `content` should contain either a string (or strings) or url of image wrapped in `url()` function (and then image will be inserted like a real `IMG` element).

Take into account that, to make generated pseudoelement visible (if you will use `background-image` instead of `content: url(path)`), `content` property should contain at least empty string (`""`) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Content accepts only text. for special charter like space you must use hex format. I change it like follow and worked. but for increase width, repeat space hex(\00a0).

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:after {
background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32/file_extension_pdf.png') ;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0"
}
```